# Comparing computed vs a copy (Vue js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've asked the question here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/comparing-computed-vs-a-copy/34542, and am not getting any traction.

TL;DR Using Vue JS computed seems to re-evaluate for properties that the computed doesn't depend on.

Below is a jsfiddle showing an oddity (maybe explainable) that I’ve encountered with computeds.

Original:
https://jsfiddle.net/1v58dj8x/3/

With Roy's suggestions:
https://jsfiddle.net/1v58dj8x/4/

Vue js properties:

```
data:
    {
        items: [],
        copy: [],
        starti: 0,
        endi: 100,
        total: 5000
    },
```

The example shows two graphs with the same data. One is a computed (of items) and another is just a copy of a larger data set (also items). I would assume that during access and without its dependencies changing, the computed should be just as fast as a copy of the same data.

In fact it is if one just calls points() over and over. However, if I change starti or endi, then it seems that vue is re-evaluating the underlying dependencies (items). I don’t understand why this is. I would expect it to not re-evaluate as starti and endi are not (to my eye) dependencies.

The second issue I have with this, is that the first computed run takes a very long time. However, it’s less of a concern as initial loading is easily concealed with a loading animation.

If one changes the number of data points (i.e. mess with total), you can see the difference in time on both access and load isn’t linear. In a couple of projects, I have just stuck with the copy of the data in favor of speed, but I’d like clarity here as I could most likely not be using this library (Vue js) correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I got a tremendous initial speedup by rewriting `filter`:

```
        filter: function()
        {
            let ret = this.items
              .filter((i) => i.type === 'criteria')
              .map((i) => ({name: i.name, value: i.value}));

            return ret;
        },
```

It looks like indexing operations on observable (computed or not) arrays are fairly expensive.

This also performed well:

```
    filter: function() {
      let ret = [];

      this.items.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.type == 'criteria')
          ret.push({
            'name': item.name,
            'value': item.value
          });
      });

      return ret;
    },
```

I also modified `points` to stop indexing `filtereditems` (see the first and last lines here):

```
      const items = this.filtereditems;
      for (let i = this.starti; i < end; ++i) {
        let x = i * 5 + 100;
        let y = items[i].value + 200;
```

and `points` is now faster than `points4copy`. (Editing `points4copy` in the same way speeds it up, too.)

The lesson: avoid indexing observable arrays.

Comment: Thanks Roy. I appreciate the response. Seems that this would be an effective work-around. I'll definitely avoid using indexing on an observable.

I still think it would re-evaluate a computed's dependencies given any other vue property changes, which is what I was trying to show in this somewhat contrived example. Not sure if this is by design, or if it is a bug.

Again, thanks.

Comment: Computeds *should* only re-evaluate when a dependency changes.